# Automate the process of managing (upgrade/new) VMWare through Vsphere from TestComplete

Tags: powershell, vmware, testcomplete

We are looking to automate the process of managing(Upgrade/New) VMWare through Vsphere from Test Complete.

The general flow is:

a. Launch Vsphere client 
b. Navigate to specific Cluster in Vsphere
c. Power On Respective Server VM or Create a new VM

Any pointers for the above implementation will be helpful. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

VMware vSphere has [API with libraries for many languages](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vapi/index.html). You can use its Java or .NET version to work with vSphere from TestComplete with its [Java Bridge](http://smartbear.com/viewarticle/81074/) or [CLR Bridge](http://smartbear.com/viewarticle/80911/) features.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like TestComplete supports multiple scripting languages. I would say the easiest way to do what you want would be to use [VMware PowerCLI](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/PowerCLI/index.html) (a PowerShell module/suite for managing vSphere and other VMware products) to automate this process.

Basic PowerCLI script you would use would be:

```
Connect-VIServer Your_vCenter_FQDN_or_IP_here -username first.last -password yourloginpassword
$existingVM = Get-Cluster CLUSTERNAME | Get-VM VMNAME
if ($existingVM)
{
    Start-VM $existingVM
}
else 
{
    New-VM -Name VMNAME # probably need a few more mandatory paramaters specified here...
}
```